# How to estimate parameters of TransformedProcess?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Let's say we have the following time-series.

```
proc=TransformedProcess[x[t]+y[t],{x\[Distributed]
CompoundPoissonProcess[.05,NormalDistribution[0,1]],y\[Distributed] ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]x[t] == 0.01*x[t]* \[DifferentialD]t +
Sqrt[x[t]] \[DifferentialD]w[t], x[t], {x, 1}, t,
w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]]},t]
```

I can simulation this process,but cannnot estimate directly.

Any ideas?